# Is Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare cross-play compatible between Xbox 360 and PS3?

Tags: xbox-360, ps3, call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

Can you play Xbox 360 with Call of Duty Advanced Warfare online with Call of Duty Advanced Warfare for PS3?

Comment: In the future, please try to make your title relevant to the question being asked.

Answer (score 7):

No you cannot there is no cross play between Xbox 360 and PS3.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't. There is no cross-play in CoD Advanced Warfare.

Comment: Looks like someone had the same idea as me huh? :D

Comment: @Ramirez that's right :D